# How to make Gallio remember which categories of tests I want to run when reloading the Tests Explorer TreeView?

Tags: unit-testing, gallio, test-runner

If I have a loaded assembly in Gallio, and I select a couple of Tests and click "Start" it will run those tests and still remember which tests were selected.

On the other hand, if I hit "Reload", it will forget which tests I had selected (rendering the feature kinda useless). Is there any way to prevent this behaviour? I have my tests defined in several categories, and I want to always automatically run the "Unit-Test" category tests, when compiling my project in Visual Studio.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in [Icarus](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=tools:icarus) test runner (see [issue 707](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/detail?id=707)). I'm not aware of any workaround for the moment, but it should hopefully be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in the trunk, and should be in the next release.